# ASP.net create infinite loop on application start to do work

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webforms

I need to do some work on periodic basis, like check some data in DB and make some calculations if needed and store them back to DB.

The question is how bad is it to start infinite look with some "sleep and do work" in separate thread on application start which would perform all required task periodically until pool shutdown?

What are the downsides? it feels for me like it may affect asp.net processing performance due to reusable/releasable concept of MVC resources, but I can't find any proof.

Would appreciate any links or hints, Thanks!

P.S. I realize that best place to do something like this is windows service but it introduce some difficulties with deployment on client environment and I am checking out for any other options if any.

Comment: asp.net / mvc really isn't the place for something like this, but it you are going to do it there take a look at [Hangfire](https://www.hangfire.io/)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you construct a simple Console App to do what you would like and then set a Scheduled Task to run the console app.

This is the method I have used to do maintenance utilities such as the one you are describing.

Otherwise, in an Asp.net app, the worker process could be reset, the host might have an Idle Timeout triggered. And generally I think it would be the wrong approach when a very simple console app will use the language you prefer and accomplish the same task.

Comment: Unfortunately any application would not start until someone login to the server, so it isn't going to work on web server. But anyway thanks for confirming my doubts regarding running infinite look in worker process.

Comment: "Unfortunately any application would not start until someone login to the server"

That's what the scheduled task is for. But if you would like, you can trigger the maintenance-style task on application start, or on user login, by embedding a call to the console app (or other code in your project) inside the global.asax, Application_Start() method for example.

Comment: start task from web worker when I need - it may work, thanks for an idea.